# Pricebook and currency

Tags: currency, pricebook

We have set-up products with a USD and CND price. We have multi-currency set-up in SFDC.
When I set an opportunity to USD and select products, it all works fine.
But when I set the opp to CND, no products appear in the product list.
How do I get to see and select products that have CND pricing?

Answer (score 8):

My experience with this is that

- Standard Pricebook needs to have active prices for USD and CND for the product in question
- Pricebook X needs to have active prices for both USD and CND for the product in question
- Through the Add Products UI button, you select pricebook X

Comment: That is correct. A single product can be offered in a single price book in multiple currencies, so there is no need to have separate price books.

Comment: In addition, I had problems because we had the box labelled "Allow Support to Activate Multiple Currencies" ticked but "Activate Multiple Currencies" was missing. Salesforce support need to make the actual change.